# Physical representation of python array in html

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I have physical 2-d array of widgets that are cataloged in a database according to the following format:

database

```
id | plate | loc_index
-------------------
0  | g394e |  4
1  | d23e9 |  16
2  | f98d9 |  8
3  | w2340 |  3
4  | fl120 |  7
5  | f990d |  1
6  | e19f9 |  13
7  | t20f9 |  10
```

I would like to represent the plates on a django webapp according to their physical position (index) in the world.

UI display

```
Plate representation
col1      col2      col3      col4      
f990d                         e19f9 
                    t20f9
w2340     fl120 
g394e     f98d9               d23e9
```

django

views.py

```
def index(request):
  plates = [(0, 'g394e', 4), 
    (1, 'd23e9', 16),
    (2, 'f98d9', 8),
    (3, 'w2340', 3),
    (4, 'fl120', 7),
    (5, 'f990d', 1),
    (6, 'e19f9', 13),
    (7, 't20f9', 10)]
  context = { 'plates': plates }
  return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

index.html

```
<script>
    $( function() {
    $( "#selectable" ).selectable();
  } );
</script>

<ul class="ul-col-4" id="selectable">
  {% for plate in plates %}
    <li class="ui-widget-content">{{ plate }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

additional.css

```
.ul-col-4 {
    columns: 4;
    -webkit-columns: 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-columns: 4; /* Firefox */
    list-style-type: none; /* no bullets */
}
```

With this html code, the plates just fill as they are, without skipping elements where the 'loc_index' is empty. I suppose one approach may be to find all missing loc_index values and fill with an empty string, but is there a more elegant bootstrap / html way?

*Update in response to iamkhush

When the index is empty the html view looks like:

```
g394e  d23e9  f98d9  w2340
fl120  f990d  e19f9  t20f9
```

Comment: what if you add a default in loc_index field in database?

Comment: Also, its not clear what happens when you have loc_index empty. Can you show that as well?

Comment: I have a read-only relationship with the database, I can only do post-processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is iterating through the eight items in your plates list but does not account for the blank "cells" in your list.  You either need to include these blank cells in the data you are sending to the client or update your javascript to insert blank `<li>&nbsp;</li>` in the appropriate locations.  The first approach would look like this:

```
plates = [(0, 'g394e', 4), 
    (1, 'd23e9', 16),
    (2, 'f98d9', 8),
    (3, 'w2340', 3),
    (4, 'fl120', 7),
    (5, 'f990d', 1),
    (6, 'e19f9', 13),
    (7, 't20f9', 10),
    (8, '', 2),
    (9, '', 4),
    etc, etc....]
```

The second approach is more difficult because it would require a numerical for loop in a Django template, which is a no-no.

```
  {% for x in ***range (1,16)*** %} #Not allowed in templates
    {% if plate.x %}
      <li class="ui-widget-content">{{ plate }}</li>
    {% else %}
      <li class="ui-widget-content">&nbsp;</li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

You would have to figure out a workaround for this shortcoming in Django's template language.  This solution would be "cleaner" imho but it's not supported in a senseible way in Django.  The first solution is the easiest.